# Python on_member_join not working with discord bot

Tags: python, discord.py

My on_member_join command won’t work for a discord bot, and I’m not 100% sure why, I’ve tried multiple stuff and none worked (picture below for code)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArksG.jpg)

Comment: Do you have members intents enabled for your bot?

Answer (score 0):

[`client.fetch_channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=fetch_channel#discord.Client.fetch_channel) requires the intake of a channel ID, not the channel name.

You also require the `Members Intent`:

You will have to enable it [here](https://discord.com/developers/applications). Select the application you want it on -> Select `Bot` -> SERVER MEMBERS INTENT and then make sure it shows blue next to it. Then click Save Changes. Since you are developing your bot you might want to enable Presence intent as well to save you time later.

You will then have to edit your bot variable like so:

```py
intents = discord.Intents()
intents.all()

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".", intents=intents)
```